# How to call Swift function with breakpoint from LLDB?

Tags: swift, lldb

I know a Swift function by name and wanted to call the function from LLDB for debugging purposes.

I tried doing:

```
expr -- function_with_a_breakpoint()
```

This runs the function and parses correctly but doesn't hit the breakpoints I made. Ideally, I want to trigger from within LLDB without having to manually trigger the function from the app UI, for example. This would be more convenient.

Comment: Might also mention as part of your bonus advice that once you are done looking at the function you called by hand, `thread return -x` gets you back to the stack frame you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Swift functions with breakpoints in LLDB

I've added this answer with bonus notes since we usually trigger a Swift function from LLDB when we want to reach a breakpoint.

I enjoy working within LLDB for managing breakpoints because I don't break my flow between Xcode and the console.

### Trigger a Function

The answer to your question is here. We have to set the `-i` flag to trigger a function from LLDB:

```
(lldb) expr -i 0 -- function_with_a_breakpoint()
```

### Programmatic breakpoints

We commonly use a function trigger from LLDB to trigger a breakpoint manually.

If we want to set a breakpoint on a function and we know the name:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -n function_with_a_breakpoint
```

Using the file name and line number:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --file foo.swift --line 12
// copy the breakpoint number into the modify command below
```

We can also create the breakpoint as a one-off using the `--one-shot` flag.

```
(lldb) breakpoint modify --one-shot 1
```

### Bonus Workflow Notes

An example flow:

```
(lldb) run
(lldb) kill
... hit breakpoints...
(lldb) continue
```

So we could trigger the function after `kill` in the above example.